# Решите пожалуйста банальную задачу на java

Tags: java, task

Пошёл учиться на samsung it school, но почти не разбираюсь в программировании.

Задача A + B
Даны 2 целых числа: A и B. Требуется вычислить их сумму.

Входные данные
Во входном потоке в единственной строке через пробел записаны два целых числа: A и B (−10^9≤a,b≤10^9).

Выходные данные
В выходной поток следует записать единственное целое число — сумму чисел A и B.

Буду очень благодарен за полное расписывание программы.

Comment: то есть B = A + B? Буду отталкиваться от этого и распишу реализацию

Comment: Нет, в - это предлог. В(русская буква) выходной поток следует записать целое число - сумму чисел A и B(переменные).

Comment: Это все на самом деле азы. Навряд ли получится успешно завершить курсы от samsung, если сам не будешь это делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Создаем экземпляр Сканера и даем возможность вводить данные с одной строки через пробел или запятую
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[,\\s+]");
        //Создаем переменные и инициализируем их
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        //Переменная c равно сумме a и b
        int c = a + b;

        //В консоль выводится переменная c
        System.out.println("Output: " + c);
    }
}
```